# WYSWYG Using media browser on frontend

Tags: magento2, media

- Is possibile to use media browser of admin on frontend?
- I am meaning the pop up window when clicking browse server of wyswyg, the pop up is this image
  [image]
- I am using the webkul marketplace extension, it's using wyswyg as editor and let user enter the content of product description.
- Unfortunately, the wyswyg  on frontend is not including media browser.